# Дублирование коммитов

Tags: git

В проекте две удаленные ветки master и develop.
Работал в ветке develop, коммитил и пушил только в нее.
Сейчас доделал проект и хочу слить develop c master.
Перехожу в ветку мастер, делаю `git merge develop --no-ff -m "merge develop"`
После этого я ожидаю, что история master будет:

- initial commit
- merge develop

Получаю

- initial commit
- коммиты из ветки develop
- merge develop

Получается, что в двух ветках одинаковые коммиты.
Хотелось бы, чтобы коммиты ветки develop при слиянии с веткой master не повторялись в master, можно этого как то добиться или так и должно быть?

Comment: Похоже, вам squash нужен:  `git merge --squash develop`

Comment: не волнуйтесь, коммиты не «дублируются». это те же самые коммиты. ветка в git — это не «набор коммитов», а всего лишь плавающий указатель на коммит.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

На самом деле ваши коммиты не дублируются. Вы можете в этом убедиться набрав команду `git log --first-parent`.

Коммиты в git организованы в виде ациклического орграфа. Реальная структура коммитов у вас получается примерно такой:

```
merge commit (master)
| \
|  commit 3 (develop)
|  |
|  commit 2
|  |
|  commit 1
| /
initial commit
```

Советую для просмотра истории коммитов использовать какие-нибудь графические утилиты.

Comment: какие-нибудь графические утилиты - `git log --oneline --graph --decorate --all --simplify-by-decoration` =)

Comment: @NickVolynkin в по-настоящему сложных случаях ваш способ только запутает. Достаточно 7-8 параллельных веток - и уже будет невозможно понять какая звездочка под какой находится.

Comment: мне кажется, запутывание начинается с пяти опций )